# PreTokenGeneration invocation failed due to error Socket timeout while invoking Lambda function

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

I have created a Cognito login system and used PreSignUp and PreToken Lambda trigger but inside PreToken lambda, there is 3-4 Mongoose DB call to fetch the user data and pass that data inside that token, but when I am trying to login then

```
PreTokenGeneration invocation failed due to error Socket timeout while invoking Lambda function.
```

this error is throwing although all the cosole.log is working from PreTokenLambda, I have checked inside CloudWatch

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a bit old ticket, but I think your PreTokenGen function is taking too long to run. (Cognito has 6 sec timeout).